# NSDictionary of Blocks as argument cause overflow

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I understand blocks are objective c objects and can be put in NSDictionary directly without Block_copy when using ARC.  **But I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with this code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self method1:^(BOOL result){
        NSLog(@"method1WithBlock finished %d", result);
    }];
}

- (void) method1:(void (^)(BOOL))finish{

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:^(NSData *rcb){
        finish(YES);
    }, @"success",
                          ^(NSError *error){
                              finish(NO);
                         }, @"failure",  nil];

    [self method2:dict];
}


- (void) method2:(NSDictionary *)dict{
    void (^success)(NSData *rcb) = [dict objectForKey:@"success"];
    success(nil);
}
```

**If I change method1: to this, no error raised.**

```
- (void) method1:(void (^)(BOOL))finish{
    void (^success)(NSData *)  = ^(NSData *rcb){
        finish(YES);
    };

    void (^failure)(NSError *error) = ^(NSError *error){
        finish(NO);
    };
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:success, @"success",
                          failure, @"failure",  nil];
    [self method2:dict];
}
```

Can anybody explain why I have to use automatic variables to store the blocks before putting them to dictionary ?

I am using iOS SDK 6.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), you have to copy a block stored
in a dictionary (emphasis mine):

> Blocks “just work” when you pass blocks up the stack in ARC mode, such
>   as in a return. You don’t have to call Block Copy any more.
>   **You still need to use `[^{} copy]`** when passing “down” the stack into
>   `arrayWithObjects:` **and other methods that do a retain**.

The second method works "by chance" because `success` and `failure` are a 
`__NSGlobalBlock__` and not a "stack based block" that needs to be copied to the heap.

Comment: so the difference between the two _method1:_ is  block literal  on stack and block object  on heap?

Comment: is `__NSGlobalBlock__` documented ?

Comment: @user1122742: Actually, when you type "po dict" in the debugger in your first `method1:`, you will see that `success` is a `__NSMallocBlock__` and `error` is a `__NSStackBlock__`. The difference is probably caused by the fact that `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` takes a variable argument list. I would just leave that as in implementation detail and stick to the documentation which clearly says that you have to copy blocks that are put into an array or dictionary.

Comment: @user1122742: I don't think that `__NSGlobalBlock__` is documented, it is an implementation detail. You can have a look at http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html for some instructive explanations (but that article is pre-ARC). If you are really courageous, read http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html :-)

Comment: @MartinR so just to get this straight.. you need to do a block copy if you're storing them in an array in *both* ARC and non-ARC modes?

Comment: @abbood: Yes, that's how I understand the documentation that I linked to.

Comment: "The second method works "by chance" because success and failure are a `__NSGlobalBlock__` and not a "stack based block" that needs to be copied to the heap." No they are not. They cannot be. `__NSGlobalBlock__` is only for blocks that are not closures (don't capture any variables). Both blocks in the second example capture the local variable `finish`, and thus are closures, and cannot be global blocks.

Comment: @newacct: Strange. I am sure that `po success` showed `__NSGlobalBlock__` in the debugger console when I tested this. But now it shows `__NSMallocBlock__`. So you are right and I cannot remember what I did wrong previously.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand blocks are objective c objects and can be put in NSDictionary directly without Block_copy when using ARC.

No, they're not common objects. When you create a block it is on the stack, and it doesn't matter of what is it's retain count, when you exit form the function it will be popped from the stack. Copy it to make it stay alive.

Answer (score 0):

You must copy blocks before passing them to a method when 1) the block will be stored for longer than the duration of the call, and 2) the parameter you are passing it to is a normal object pointer type (i.e. `id` or `NSObject *`) instead of a block type.

This is the case for your call. `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` stores the argument in the resulting dictionary, and it simply expects normal object pointer arguments (of type `id`), and does not know whether you are passing blocks or not.

The reason for the second condition I said is because if the method parameter already takes a block type (e.g. for any completion handler parameters), then that method is already aware of the special memory management requirements of blocks, and therefore will take responsibility for copying the block if it needs to store it. In that case the caller doesn't need to worry about it. However, in your case, you are passing it to a general method that doesn't know it's getting a block, and thus doesn't know to copy it. So the caller must do it.

> Can anybody explain why I have to use automatic variables to store the
>   blocks before putting them to dictionary ?

About this, your second example *happens to* work because recent versions of the ARC compiler is super conservative about blocks and inserts copies whenever you assign it to a block type variable. However, this is not guaranteed by the ARC specification, and is not guaranteed to work in the future, or in another compiler. You should not rely on this behavior.